# Как сделать чтоб объект двигался в любом направлении?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Захотелось украсить свою 3D игру разными питомцами, и для красоты сделать чтоб они и передвигались, а не стояли как камень.
Например как в Minecraft, там животные передвигаются куда хотят.
Как это сделать? Если надо -  моя версия Unity является 2019.4.29f1. Выше версию скачать нету возможности. Прошу помочь.

Comment: У вас ответ в самом вопросе: движение в рандомном направлении. Так в чем проблема-то? Выбираем направление и двигаемся в нем. Или опять проблема в путанице между StackOverflow и Freelance.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть, взять координаты питомца, вычислить случайное число (допустим от 1 до 10 метров), выбрать траекторию (тоже случайно), и плавно изменять координаты питомца, а после достижения цели подождать немного и сделать все с начала?